# pattern for a function to either take an enum or a combination of enum values

Tags: c++, enums, bit-manipulation

let's say I have this:

```
enum E{ 
a,
b,
c,
total
}

class A {
char mask; // supposed to contains combinations of values of the enum, like a or c, etc
}
```

Is there a decent solution to build the object A in a user-friendly way?
For instance I could do:

```
A(E e) {
mask = 1 << e;
}
```

but this will only work if you want the mask to be made from only 1 element of the enum
Ideally the user would be able to do something like :

```
A* a = new A(a | c)
```

and this would automatically create

```
mask = 1 << a | 1 << c;
```

Any idea on how to do this correctly?
thanks

**edit**

sadly I have no control over the initial enum and the values are increasing 1 by 1

Comment: Why do you do not have control over the initial enum as you are writing the class A?

Comment: Don't use enums to specify bit values -- big headache.  We just banished enums on our medical device product.  If you **must** use enums, then let them represent the bit position and use 1 left shift to the quantity of the enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's the simple way and the ugly way.

The simple way is to define the bits as non-overlapping to being with, e.g.:

```
enum E
{ 
   a = 1 << 0,
   b = 1 << 1,
   c = 1 << 2,
   total = 1 << 3 // or a | b | c, not sure what the intent was
};
```

The ugly way:

```
#define MAKEA(x) (new A((E_helper() | x).get()))
```

where `E_helper` is a class that overrides `operator|(enum E)`.

```
class E_helper
{
    unsigned accum;
public:
    explicit E_helper(unsigned initial = 0) : accum(initial) {}
    unsigned get() const { return accum; }
    E_helper operator|(enum E e) const { return E_helper(accum | (1 << (unsigned)e)); }
};
```

And then your user can say

```
A* p = MAKEA(a | c);
```

which expands to

```
A* p = (new A((A_helper() | a | c).get());
```

which causes this chain of events

```
A_helper.operator|(a).operator|(c).get()
```

Better yet, move the `.get()` call inside A's constructor, which then takes an argument of type `A_helper`.  This will let you catch the case where the user forgot to use the `MAKEA` macro.

Be warned, however, that **the ugly way exposes counter-intuitive behavior**.  For example, `A* p = MAKEA(a | c);` is different from `A* p = MAKEA( (a | c) );` and `char mask = a | c; A* p = MAKEA(mask);`

Comment: @lezebulon: And see my expanded answer.

Comment: @Thomas: That would be useful if you need more than `sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT` flags.  Because the question is using `char mask`, I don't think that's an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In order to maintain types and also provide support for bitwise `|`, `&`, `^` I write the following operators in a macro and usually use them on enum types in my projects:

```
enum E {
    a = 1 << 0,
    b = 1 << 1,
    c = 1 << 2,
    total = a | b | c
};
E operator | (E lhs, E rhs ) {
    return static_cast<E>( static_cast<int>(lhs) | static_cast<int>(rhs) );
}
E operator & (E lhs, E rhs ) {
    return static_cast<E>( static_cast<int>(lhs) & static_cast<int>(rhs) );
}
E operator ^ (E lhs, E rhs ) {
    return static_cast<E>( static_cast<int>(lhs) ^ static_cast<int>(rhs) );
}
E operator ~ (E e ) {
    return static_cast<E>( ~static_cast<int>(e) );
}
E& operator |= (E& lhs, E rhs ) {
    return lhs = static_cast<E>( static_cast<int>(lhs) | static_cast<int>(rhs) );
}
E& operator &= (E& lhs, E rhs ) {
    return lhs = static_cast<E>( static_cast<int>(lhs) & static_cast<int>(rhs) );
}
E& operator ^= (E& lhs, E rhs ) {
    return lhs = static_cast<E>( static_cast<int>(lhs) ^ static_cast<int>(rhs) );
}
```

Now you may have:

```
void test( E e );
test( a | b );
E e = c;
e |= b;
e = e & d;
e ^= a;
e = ~e;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
enum E{ 
a = 1,
b = 2,
c = 4,

}
```

Then

```
A var(a | c)
```

will work

Then to check if (say) `a` is set you use `&` i.e. `if (mask & a) ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate bit masks from a set of contiguous values. That's straightforward:

```
int mask(E e) {
    return 1 << e;
}
```

Now you can or the mask values together to call your function:

```
A var(mask(a) | mask(b));
```